Joining lat/lon data frames by nearest distance
Let's say I have a regular latitude/longitude grid and data at irregular locations, like this:
grid = tidyr::crossing(lon = seq(0, 1, 0.25), lat = seq(0, 1, 0.25))
data = tibble::tibble(lon = runif(4), lat=runif(4), y=rnorm(4))

How do I use, for example, dplyr::inner_join and join_by to join these data frames so that I get y values from data and corresponding lat and lon values from grid from the nearest location, i.e. the grid point with smallest (grid$lon - data$lon)^2 + (grid$lat - data$lat)^2 for each row in data?

The package sf is made to manipulate spatial geometries; ex. points, lines, polygones. You need to convert the dataframes as sf objects, then you can specify a spatial join st_join() with join = st_nearest_feature as argument.
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(42)

grid <- tidyr::crossing(lon = seq(0, 1, 0.25), lat = seq(0, 1, 0.25))
data <- tibble::tibble(lon = runif(4), lat = runif(4), y = rnorm(4))

grid_sf = st_as_sf(grid , coords =c("lon","lat"))
data_sf = st_as_sf(data , coords =c("lon","lat"))

joined = st_join(grid_sf, data_sf, join = st_nearest_feature)

ggplot() + geom_sf(data= joined, aes(col = y))+ 
  geom_sf(data= data_sf, aes(col = y, fill = y),size= 4, shape = 22)


Created on 2024-07-12 with reprex v2.1.0

Nice! Would it be possible to add a line to the code where you transform joined so that it has columns lon and lat?

@sieste, my suggestion would be to keep lon and lat in data_sf (with remove=FALSE), so these numerical columns will appears in joined:
data_sf = st_as_sf(data , coords =c("lon","lat"), remove = FALSE)

@sieste, keep in mind that this solution will work with "projected" coordinates eg. in meters. If your coordinates are in degrees, the distances wont be the same at the equator or near the poles. sf can manage multiples coordinate reference system (CRS). (I don't know how my solution would work with unprojected data (in degrees), I usually work with projected coordinates). Geospatial is nice, but sometimes hard!  A nice reference is https://r-spatial.org/book/

You can merge the 2 dataframes and search for lowest distance per coordinates group:
grid = tidyr::crossing(lon_grid = seq(0, 1, 0.25), lat_grid = seq(0, 1, 0.25))
data = tibble::tibble(lon = runif(4), lat=runif(4), y=rnorm(4))

library(dplyr)
tidyr::expand_grid(data, grid) %>%
  group_by(lon, lat) %>%
  filter(row_number() == which.min((lon_grid - lon) ^ 2 + (lat_grid - lat) ^ 2)) %>%
  ungroup()


# A tibble: 4 × 5
    lon    lat       y lon_grid lat_grid
  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 0.612 0.208   0.0407     0.5      0.25
2 0.381 0.520   2.01       0.5      0.5 
3 0.198 0.399  -0.455      0.25     0.5 
4 0.150 0.0847 -0.717      0.25     0  

For large dataframes, you can filter on points that have coordinates at resolution to reduce group numbers:
data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(grid = list(grid[(abs(grid$lon_grid - lon) < 0.25 & abs(grid$lat_grid - lat) < 0.25), ])) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(grid) %>%
  group_by(lon, lat) %>%
  filter(row_number() == which.min((lon_grid - lon) ^ 2 + (lat_grid - lat) ^ 2)) %>%
  ungroup()


Thanks, that's definitely a good solution for small data sets. But for larger ones the intermediate data frame of size nrow(grid) * nrow(data) might make this impractical. Is there a solution that avoids this?

Answer updated. Please have a look :)

If the grid is uniform you can simply round to the grid granularity.
set.seed(42)

grid <- tidyr::crossing(lon = seq(0, 1, 0.25), lat = seq(0, 1, 0.25))
data <- tibble::tibble(lon = runif(4), lat = runif(4), y = rnorm(4))

round_to <- function(x, precision) {
  precision * round(x / precision)
}

data |>
  dplyr::mutate(
    lon_grid = round_to(lon, 0.25),
    lat_grid = round_to(lat, 0.25),
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>     lon   lat       y lon_grid lat_grid
#>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 0.915 0.642  0.404      1        0.75
#> 2 0.937 0.519 -0.106      1        0.5 
#> 3 0.286 0.737  1.51       0.25     0.75
#> 4 0.830 0.135 -0.0947     0.75     0.25

For joining arbitrary points, you’ll need to calculate all the pairwise
distances. That can be done efficiently with Rfast::dista().
data |>
  dplyr::mutate(
    grid_index = dplyr::pick(lon, lat) |>
      Rfast::dista(grid[c("lon", "lat")]) |>
      Rfast::rowMins(),
    grid[grid_index, ] |> dplyr::rename_all(paste0, "_grid")
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 × 6
#>     lon   lat       y grid_index lon_grid lat_grid
#>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 0.915 0.642  0.404          24     1        0.75
#> 2 0.937 0.519 -0.106          23     1        0.5 
#> 3 0.286 0.737  1.51            9     0.25     0.75
#> 4 0.830 0.135 -0.0947         17     0.75     0.25


Here is a base R approach using max.col + outer
cp_grid <- with(grid, lon + 1i * lat)
cp_data <- with(data, lon + 1i * lat)
cbind(
    data,
    setNames(
        grid,
        paste0("grid_", names(grid))
    )[max.col(-abs(outer(cp_data, cp_grid, `-`))), ]
)

which gives result looking like
        lon       lat          y grid_lon grid_lat
1 0.8966972 0.9082078  0.4146414     1.00     1.00
2 0.2655087 0.2016819 -1.5399500     0.25     0.25
3 0.3721239 0.8983897 -0.9285670     0.25     1.00
4 0.5728534 0.9446753 -0.2947204     0.50     1.00

Data
set.seed(0)
grid <- tidyr::crossing(lon = seq(0, 1, 0.25), lat = seq(0, 1, 0.25))
data <- tibble::tibble(lon = runif(4), lat = runif(4), y = rnorm(4))

